# Can I user AdSence Code in User Control in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, adsense

I think it is not the feasible way out here to ask. But, Can I use AdSense code in UserControl in ASP.NET?
If I use it in User Control, does the Same ad will be displayed at all the places where the User Control is used?

PS: This Question will be deleted up on suggestion, if it is not useful for future viewers of SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> does the Same ad will be displayed at all the places where the User Control is used?

No, Ad will be different according to page...as User control renders along with page where its used..so when your page 'll render. Your user control will render also..and new request for Adsense code will go to google to display a different ad.